# Borrar en cascada en MySQL con DELETE

Tags: sql

Tengo 3 tablas en mi base de datos de `MySQL`.

```
Clientes (existe el DNI)
Clientes_compra (puede existir el DNI o quizás no).
Clientes_alquiler (puede existir el DNI o quizás no).
```

Mi intención es pedir por un programa Java el textfield_DNI y si coincide con un `DNI` de la tabla `clientes` que lo borre de esta tabla y de las otras dos, si existe.

```
DELETE FROM clientes WHERE dni="13225217P";
DELETE FROM clientes_compra WHERE dni="13225217P";
DELETE FROM clientes_alquiler WHERE dni="13225217P";
```

Creo que existe la eliminación en cascada (**CASCADE ON**), ¿cómo sería en una sola consulta y no tener que usar 3?

Ejecucción de error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`osmarentcars`.`clientes_alquiler`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CLIENTES_ALQUILER1` FOREIGN KEY (`DNI`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`DNI`))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Si** quieres usar un `CONSTRAINT`, lo que tienes que hacer es declarar un `FOREIGN KEY`, un vinculo entre los campos `dni` de las tablas. En MySql se ve por ejemplo en el `CREATE TABLE` de clientes_compra como:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (dni) REFERENCES clientes (dni) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**NO** lo recomiendo. Eso significa que en el caso que tu borras un cliente, se borran automáticamente todas las compras con el mismo valor de `dni`, sin error, sin preguntar.

En el caso ideal declaras una transacción, y haces 3 consultas, borrando primero las filas en las tablas dependientes y al fin la entrada en clientes.

No hay ninguna razon logica de ponerse flojo con un par de líneas de código, sacrificando un buen concepto de seguridad de datos en el proceso.

Si insistes por alguna razón de hacerlo con una consulta, lo que debería funcionar es (si recuerdo bien la sequencia en que la BD borra)

```
DELETE ca, cc, c 
FROM clientes_alquilier ca 
LEFT JOIN clientes_compra cc 
    ON ca.dni = cc.dni 
LEFT JOIN clientes c 
    ON c.dni = cc.dni 
WHERE c.dni = "13225217P";
```

Comment: Entonces no me vale. Me gustaría que eliminara los datos correspondientes a ese DNI tanto en la tabla clientes como en las tablas clientes_compra o clientes_alquiler (depende si existe en estas o no).

Comment: Disculpa, hace exactamente lo que tu quieres, lo voy a aclarar en la respuesta. Lo que yo dudo es que **quieres** hacer eso, es bastante riesgoso.

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo quedaría la consulta?

Comment: Voy a elaborar en la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas

```
DELETE c, cc, ca 
FROM clientes c 
LEFT JOIN clientes_compra cc 
    ON c.dni = cc.dni 
LEFT JOIN clientes_alquiler ca 
    ON ca.dni = c.dni 
WHERE c.dni = "13225217P";
```

Comment: Este método no es que preguntaste, pero la mejor solucion para tu causa. Es mejor que usar un `CONSTRAINT` con `ON DELETE CASCADE`, porque no hace nada implícito.

Comment: La sintaxis está bien pero hay un error en tu código.

Comment: MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`osmarentcars`.`clientes_compra`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CLIENTES_COMPRA1` FOREIGN KEY (`DNI`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`DNI`))

Comment: Ah, tu ya tienes los `FOREIGN KEYS`. El código esta bien, tu concepto no lo es. En realidad estos `CONSTRAINTS` son exactamente para protegerte de causar inconsistencias en tu BD, y aun que lo usas, luego preguntas como evitar que no te molestan. Es como instalar tres candados en una puerta para después dejarla abierto porque molesta de siempre tener que andar con las llaves.

Comment: Eso es, yo ya los tengo en la creación de las tablas. ¿Por qué me da el error?

Comment: Te da el error porque cuando declaraste los `FOREIGN KEY` **explícitamente** pediste a la BD de no permitirte este manera de trabajar con tus tablas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52098/discussion-between-stefan-nolde-and-omaza1990).

Comment: Error de repente al abrir el proyecto de nuevo.