# Eliminar datos de dos tablas

Tags: sql, mysqli

Estoy desarrollando un e-commerce, del cual tengo dos tablas principals:

**pd_cart**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

**pd_order_status**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Intenté eliminar lo siguiente:

```
mysqli_query($this->conexao,"DELETE S FROM pd_order_status S
                                INNER JOIN pd_cart C
                                        ON S.status_cart_token = C.cart_token
                                     WHERE S.status_date < NOW()
                                       AND S.status_order = 'A';")
```

Pero solo está excluido de la mesa de pd_order_status y no de la pd_cart. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué nos quieres decir con esto: *Pero solo está excluido de la mesa de pd_order_status y no de la pd_cart*? ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Qué hace tu consulta actual y qué debería hacer? Pon un ejemplo que ayude a entender el asunto. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, ¿Quieres hacer una eliminación en cascada? ¿Te sirve esta pregunta? [Borrar en cascada en MySQL con DELETE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/45007/80870)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo la tabla que te falta en el borrado:

```
SET @@foreign_key_checks=0;
DELETE S,C
    FROM pd_order_status S
    JOIN pd_cart C ON S.status_cart_token = C.cart_token
    WHERE S.status_date < NOW() AND S.status_order = 'A';
```

Probablemente no te borre porque tengas definida una clave ajena.